# Unable to receive notification in foreground on Android 8 using react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, react-native-firebase

**I am unable to get notification in Foreground on Android 8 only. Also unable to get control on Background notification.** *But on Android version below 8 working fine with current implementation.*

**Steps followed:-**

1. Installing react-native-firebase plugin version 5.0.0 into application.
2. Created project on firebase console and added google_service.json file into android/app folder.
3. In AndroidManifest added below code:-

> ```
>      <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
>       <intent-filter>
>           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
>       </intent-filter>
>     </service>
>     <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService>
>       <intent-filter>
>           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
>       </intent-filter>
>     </service>
> <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService"/>
>
>    <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver"/>
>    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
>       <intent-filter>
>           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
>           <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
>           <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
>           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>       </intent-filter>
>    </receiver>
>    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
>    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="test_app"/>
> ```

4. Below function is added on App.js page and calling in componentDidMountMethod():-

> ```
> performNotificationOperations(){
>   this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message: RemoteMessage) => {
>     console.log("Message",message);
>     alert("Notification Message Arrived");
>     if(this.state.isLogin){
>       const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
>                         .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
>                         .setTitle(message.data.show_name)
>                         .setBody(message.data.description)
>                         .setData(message.data)
>                         .android.setChannelId('test_app')
>                         .android.setBigPicture(message.data.showImage)
>                         .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);
>       firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification).catch(err => alert("Error On Message"));
>     }
>   });
>   this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification: Notification) => {
>     console.log("Notification=>",notification);
>     alert("Notification Arrived");
>     if(this.state.isLogin){
>       notification.android.setChannelId('test_app')
>       notification.android.setBigPicture(notification._data.showImage);
>       notification.android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
>       firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification).catch(err => alert("Error On Notification"));
>     }
>   });
>   this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
>     console.log(notificationOpen,"Opened listener");
>     console.log(notificationOpen.notification._data.type,"notificationOpen");
>     firebase.notifications().removeDeliveredNotification(notificationOpen.notification._notificationId)
>     if(this.state.isLogin){
>       if(notificationOpen.notification._data.type==='show'){
>         Navigate.forward('myshowdetails', this._navigator, {show:notificationOpen.notification._data});
>       }else if(notificationOpen.notification._data.type==='episode'){
>         this.playEpisode(notificationOpen.notification._data.episodeToken);
>         Navigate.forward('myshowdetails', this._navigator, {show:notificationOpen.notification._data});
>       }
>     }
>   });
>   firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification()
>   .then((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
>     if (notificationOpen) {
>       alert('Initial Notification');
>       console.log(notificationOpen,"notificationOpen");
>       console.log(notificationOpen.notification._data.type,"notificationOpen");
>       firebase.notifications().removeDeliveredNotification(notificationOpen.notification._notificationId)
>       if(this.state.isLogin){
>         alert('IS LOGIN TRUE');
>         if(notificationOpen.notification._data.type==='show'){
>           Navigate.forward('showdetails', this._navigator, {show:notificationOpen.notification._data});
>         }else if(notificationOpen.notification._data.type==='episode'){
>           this.playEpisode(notificationOpen.notification._data.episodeToken);
>           Navigate.forward('showdetails', this._navigator, {show:notificationOpen.notification._data});
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   });
>   firebase.messaging().getToken().then(token => {
>     console.log("GCM Token====>>>>>>>>",token);
>     Global.GCM_TOKEN=token;
>     // alert(token);
>     if(Global.IS_USER_LOGIN){
>       Util.saveFCMToken(token);
>     }
>   });
> }
> ```

- Added bgMessage.js file to handle data messages and registered Headless JS service using AppRegistery.

> ```
>     // @flow
> import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
> // Optional flow type
> import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';
> import type { Notification,NotificationOpen} from 'react-native-firebase';
>
> export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
>     // handle your message
>     // console.log("Message=>",message);
>     alert("Message Arrived");
>     const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
>                       .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
>                       .setTitle(message.data.show_name)
>                       .setBody(message.data.description)
>                       .setData(message.data)
>                       .android.setChannelId('podpitara_app')
>                       .android.setBigPicture(message.data.showImage)
>                       .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);
>     firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification).catch(err => alert("Error in Background"));
>     return Promise.resolve();
> }
> ```

- **Headless JS service call:-**

> AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () =>
>   bgMessaging);

- **Additional Information:-**

> Platform - Android
>
> node-version - v8.6.0
>
> react-native - 0.57.0
>
> react-native-firebase - 0.5.0

- **Problems facing**

  1. Unable to receive notification in Foreground in case of Android 8 only.
  2. In case of background/minimized state, want to show notification with big picture, but not getting control from where I can handle displaying notification.
  3. In case of debug mode application displaying image peroperly int notification tray, but in case of release its not showing image.

**Please let me know, What I am doing wrong.**

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the same issue since I updated to Android 8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it to work.

It's because from Android 8 you need to create a channel

```
// Build a channel
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('test-channel', 'Test Channel', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
  .setDescription('My apps test channel');

// Create the channel
firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
```

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/notifications/android-channels

I was only using

```
android.setChannelId(message.data.channelId)
```

Now it shows while the app is in the foreground.

My full function is like this

```
const newNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
            .android.setChannelId(message.data.channelId)
            .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
            .setTitle(message.data.title)
            .setBody(message.data.body)
            .setSound("default")
            .setData(message.Data)
            .android.setAutoCancel(true)
            .android.setSmallIcon('ic_notification')
            .android.setCategory(firebase.notifications.Android.Category.Alarm)

    // Build a channel
    const channelId = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(message.data.channelId, channelName, firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max);

    // Create the channel
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channelId);
    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(newNotification)
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
componentDidMount()
    {     
    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
            'channelId',
            'Channel Name',
            firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
          ).setDescription('A natural description of the channel');
          firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

          this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {

              const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
                .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
                .setTitle(notification.title)
                .setSubtitle(notification.subtitle)
                .setBody(notification.body)
                .setData(notification.data)
                .android.setSmallIcon("app_icon_name") // use mipmap icon name(have not tried drawable icon)
                .android.setChannelId('channelId') 

                .android.setColor('#ffffff') // you can set a color here
                .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

              firebase.notifications()
                .displayNotification(localNotification)
                .catch(err => console.error(err));

            }   });
    }
```